# There is any way to configure port listening based on the interface? (linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, samba, nat

I have this samba service running on a box with 2 network interfaces. I can't redirect incoming connections on port 445 because it is being used by this service:

```
#ssh -fgNL 445:192.168.0.2:445 user@localhost
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 445
```

There is any way to make the samba service to listen an specific interface, while connections on the other interface are redirected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bind interfaces only = True
interfaces = eth0 192.168.0.2
```

in smb.conf so it will listen only to that interface

Comment: Yay                !